# Global PHP functions chaining through a Class

Tags: php, methods, chaining

Is it possible to chain all PHP functions through an object/class?

I have this on my mind and I imagine it something like this:

```
$c = new Chainer();

$c->strtolower('StackOverFlow')->ucwords(/* the value from the first function argument */)->str_replace('St', 'B', /* the value from the first function argument */);
```

this should produce:

```
Backoverflow
```

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "all PHP functions"? All built-in PHP functions e.g. string, array, mysql functions? I think it's not possible because every function should return an object.

Comment: What would be the advantage of doing that over `$c->strtolower(ucwords(str_replace('St','B','StackOverFlow')))`? Readability ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean to do `str_replace('St', 'B', ucwords(strtolower('StackOverFlow')))` ?

The methods you are calling above are functions, not methods tied to any class.  `Chainer` would have to implement these methods.  If this is what you want to do (perhaps for a different purpose and this is just an example) your implementation of `Chainer` might look like this:

```
class Chainer {
   private $string;
   public function strtolower($string) {
      $this->string = strtolower($string);
      return $this;
   }
   public function ucwords() {
      $this->string = ucwords($this->string);
      return $this;
   }
   public function str_replace($from, $to) {
      $this->string = str_replace($from, $to, $this->string);
      return $this;
   }
   public function __toString() {
      return $this->string;
   }
}
```

This would work in your above example somewhat, but you would call it like this:

```
$c = new Chainer;
echo $c->strtolower('StackOverFlow')
   ->ucwords()
   ->str_replace('St', 'B')
; //Backoverflow
```

Note that you never get the value of `/* the value from the first function argument */` back out from the chain as this wouldn't make sense.  Maybe you could do it with a global variable, but that would be quite hideous.

The point is, you can chain methods by returning `$this` each time.  The next method is called on the returned value which is the same object because you returned it (returned `$this`).  It is important to know which methods start and stop the chain.

I think that this implementation makes the most sense:

```
class Chainer {
   private $string;
   public function __construct($string = '') {
      $this->string = $string;
      if (!strlen($string)) {
         throw new Chainer_empty_string_exception;
      }
   }
   public function strtolower() {
      $this->string = strtolower($this->string);
      return $this;
   }
   public function ucwords() {
      $this->string = ucwords($this->string);
      return $this;
   }
   public function str_replace($from, $to) {
      $this->string = str_replace($from, $to, $this->string);
      return $this;
   }
   public function __toString() {
      return $this->string;
   }
}
class Chainer_empty_string_exception extends Exception {
   public function __construct() {
      parent::__construct("Cannot create chainer with an empty string");
   }
}

try {
   $c = new Chainer;
   echo $c->strtolower('StackOverFlow')
      ->ucwords()
      ->str_replace('St', 'B')
   ; //Backoverflow
}
catch (Chainer_empty_string_exception $cese) {
   echo $cese->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: @Phil just a coincidence, it's not that hard to figure out, though.  I actually dislike your implementation because you allow for the string to be set later by the other methods which makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php

especially:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.methods

and propably:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php

As so many posted their examples, I'll try too:

```
<?php
class Chainer
{
    protected $buffer = null;

    public function __call($name, $args) {
        if (method_exists($this, $name)) {
            $this->buffer = call_user_func_array(array($this, $name), $args);
        }
        elseif (function_exists($name)) {
            if ($this->buffer !== null) {
                $args[] = $this->buffer;
            }

            $this->buffer = call_user_func_array($name, $args);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function strpos($needle, $offset = 0) {
        return strpos($this->buffer, $needle, $offset);
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return (string)$this->buffer;
    }
}

$c = new Chainer();
echo $c->strtolower('StackOverFlow')->ucwords()->str_replace('St', 'B')->strpos('overflow'); // output: 4
```

Comment: Yes! This is what I really needed. Never quite understood those magic functions till now.

Comment: That's going to break on the first function that doesn't accept the subject parameter as the last argument

Comment: Correct. This is just an example of how `__call` could be used.

Comment: yes, you're right about 100%, but I can always filter that somehow ;)

Comment: I changed the example code, to include an idea of how special cases could be handled. (See the strpos and method_exists parts)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this provided the `Chainer` class looks something like

```
class Chainer
{
    private $string;

    public function __construct($string = null)
    {
        $this->setString($string);
    }

    public function setString($string)
    {
        $this->string = $string;
        return $this;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->string;
    }

    public function strtolower($string = null)
    {
        if (null !== $string) {
            $this->setString($string);
        }
        $this->string = strtolower($this->string);
        return $this;
    }

    public function ucwords($string = null)
    {
        if (null !== $string) {
            $this->setString($string);
        }
        $this->string = ucwords($this->string);
        return $this;
    }

    public function str_replace($search, $replace, $string = null)
    {
        if (null !== $string) {
            $this->string = $string;
        }
        $this->string = str_replace($search, $replace, $this->string);
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Looks pretty silly to me though.

You might be able to incorporate a magic `__call` method but it's going to be a major pain to deal with the stored variable and optional method arguments.

Comment: @metadata Pfft, why does the [alot](http://hyperboleandahalf.blogspot.com/2010/04/alot-is-better-than-you-at-everything.html) get all the praise?